# HEAD request always result in a TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I'm using `fetch` with `HEAD` method to check files etags on cloudinary after having dowloaded it and it's working nicely on iOS, but on Android my `HEAD` request always result in a `TypeError: Network request failed`. I have no clue how to go around this.

```
fetch('https://res.cloudinary.com/****/wycoc7svs.m4a', { method: 'HEAD' })
  .then(response => console.log({ response }))
  .catch(error => console.log({ error }));
```

I also tried using `axios.head` to see if it was different but same result.

Note that the same request with `GET` method is working fine, but that makes me download the file twice.

I'm using Expo SDK 33.

Help on this will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Look in your adb debug log. There might be more output/hints in there

Comment: There's nothing more than `TypeError: Network request failed`

Comment: do you have any kind of a network firewall / device? I'd also consider pointing the Android device networking settings to a local HTTP Proxy (such as Charles Proxy) to look at the raw HTTP request to see whats happening.